# Fast algorithm to calculate 3D ray / triangle edge intersections for a large number of triangles

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a triangle ABC in 3D space and a ray in plane of the triangle given by starting point E (always inside or on the triangle's edge) and direction vector d.

The vertices A, B and C as well as E and d are given in 3D coordinates {x,y,z}.

I am looking for an algorithm to calculate the intersection of the ray with the triangle's edge P.

I can do 3 ray / line segment intersection tests for the 3 edges of the triangle but since I have to do this for a large number of triangles I am looking for a more efficient and faster algorithm.

1. What is the best way to do this?
2. Could Barycentric Coordinates help?

[image]

Comment: As in [math-stackexchange][1] the complexity to compute these three intersection tests is in O(1). I doubt that (2) changing the coordinate system will help you much. (1) More interesting is what do you mean by: "I  have to do this for a large number of triangles". Maybe you can add the rest of the problem you are dealing with to simplify giving advice. 

  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2139740/fast-3d-algorithm-to-find-a-ray-triangle-edge-intersection/2140591#2140591

Comment: you have to group your triangles spatially and check only groups near your ray ... in camera direction Z order

Comment: The way I read it, you are essentially in a 2d setup: all your points appear to be in one plane. Is that right?

Comment: Is the ray always the same ? Are the ray and the triangles coplanar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could Barycentric Coordinates help?

It may. It depends a bit on how highly optimized your non-barycentric code is, but I'd say that using barycentric coordinates it's at least easier to write code which is both maintainable and performant.

As far as I can tell, your whole setup is essentially 2d, with both the point `E` and the direction `d` contained within the plane spanned by `A,B,C`. So you have

```
E = aE*A + bE*B + cE*C  with aE+bE+cE=1
d = ad*A + bd*B + cd*C  with ad+bd+cd=0
```

Now you have two subproblems:

1. How to obtain the barycentric coordinates efficiently
2. How to find the point of intersection

Let's start with the latter. You simply add to `E` as many multiples of `d` until the `c` coordinate becomes zero.

```
P = E - (cE/cd)*d
```

Depending on your setup, you might also be fine using homogeneous coordinates, in which case you could write this as `P = cd*E - cE*d`.

How do you turn `x,y,z` coordinates of `d` and `E` into barycentric `a,b,c`? Well, that's just a system of linear equations. You could use the inverse of the matrix formed by the vectors `A,B,C`. Again, if you are dealing with homogeneous coordinates, you can use the adjunct instead of the inverse.

Here is the homogeneous approach spelled out:

```
aE = (By*Cz-Bz*Cy)*Ex + (Bz*Cx-Bx*Cz)*Ey + (Bx*Cy-By*Cx)*Ez
bE = (Cy*Az-Cz*Ay)*Ex + (Cz*Ax-Cx*Az)*Ey + (Cx*Ay-Cy*Ax)*Ez
cE = (Ay*Bz-Az*By)*Ex + (Az*Bx-Ax*Bz)*Ey + (Ax*By-Ay*Bx)*Ez
ad = (By*Cz-Bz*Cy)*dx + (Bz*Cx-Bx*Cz)*dy + (Bx*Cy-By*Cx)*dz
bd = (Cy*Az-Cz*Ay)*dx + (Cz*Ax-Cx*Az)*dy + (Cx*Ay-Cy*Ax)*dz
cd = (Ay*Bz-Az*By)*dx + (Az*Bx-Ax*Bz)*dy + (Ax*By-Ay*Bx)*dz
aP = cd*aE - cE*ad
bP = cd*bE - cE*bd
Px = aP/(aP+bP)*Ax + bP/(aP+bP)*Bx
Py = aP/(aP+bP)*Ay + bP/(aP+bP)*By
Pz = aP/(aP+bP)*Az + bP/(aP+bP)*Bz
```

The first three lines convert `E` to barycentric coordinates, the next three lines `d`. Then we compute the barycentric coordinates of `P`, and turn these back into Cartesian coordinates. In that step we also dehomogenize them, i.e. divide by the sum of the barycentric coordinates.

On the whole, there is a considerable amount of code here. You can reduce the number of operations by moving common expressions to dedicated variables, particularly if your compiler doesn't do that for you. One benefit is that you won't need any divisions except for the final dehomogenization, i.e. the division by `(a+b)`. If you compute `1/(a+b)` once, you can make do with but a single division, which is good for performance.

The real benefit of the above code however is likely that you can do many nice things with the barycentric coordinates that you couldn't easily do with other coordinate systems. For example, if you want to check whether the ray hits the line `AB` on the line segment or somewhere outside the triangle, just check whether `aP*bP > 0`.

Comment: Let's take an example triangle: (Ax=0, Ay=0, Az=0), (Bx=5, By=0, Bz=0), (Cx=0, Cy=5, Cz=0). Let's set E to (Ex=1, Ey=2.5, Ez=0) and d to (dx=1, dy=0, dz=0). Then we should get for the intersection with the edge BC: (Px=2.5, Py=2.5, Pz=0). The barycentric coordinates are for E (aE=0.3, bE=0.2, cE=0.5) and for d (ad=0.8, bd=0.2, cd=0). For the intersection with the edge BC the barycentric coordinate a must be zero. Thus we get P = E - (aE/ad)*d = (Px=0.625, Py=2.5, Pz=0) which is not correct. Where is my mistake?

Comment: @user3384674: The picture in your question was intersecting with the edge AB, and my code always intersects with AB. To intersect with BC you'd change some labels. But I realize that I have made a mistake turning d and E into barycentric coordinates. In your example Az=Bz=Cz=0 so the matrix ABC has a zero row and no inverse. Actually one needs one more row ensuring aE+bE+cE=1 and ad+bd+cd=0, which makes these systems overdefined since things only work if E is in the plane spanned by A,B,C and d is parallel to that plane.

Answer (score 1):

1. Time complexity is O(1)
2. It could potentially help.
   In case we are talking about 3D and all your points lie on one plane. In cartesian coordinates you need to solve three linear systems [image] to find intersection with three lines, and then determinate whether intersections lies on edge or not.
   Or you need to find barycentric coordinates of two points on line. Point A(a1,a2,a3) = E and B(b1,b2,b3) = E+d. Equation of line is 
   [image]
   Now you still need to solve three linear systems (where one of the mu = 0 and sum of the others = 1). But it will be 2x2 systems that easer to solve. And then check signes of found roots to detrerminate whether found point lies on edge or not.

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily ignore the axis for which d has the smallest component, and treat the resulting 2D problem, just as we see on your illustration.

You can precompute the equation of the line of support of the ray, in the form ax + by + c = 0 (assuming z was ignored). Plug the coordinates of the three vertices in this expression, and the signs will tell you on what side of the line the vertices are.

The two intersections with the line occur on the edges having different signs at the endpoints.

Then, to determine which is the right edge, the sign of the angle between the ray and the third egde will do (if I am right);

When you know which edge, you can compute the parameter of the parametric equation of the side, which you can deduce from the previously computed signs. For instance, along the edge AB, t = Sb / (Sb - Sa). Also compute 1 - t;

Finally, use the t value to interpolate between the endpoints, this time in 3D.

The computational cost is

- evalutation of the three signs Sa, Sb, Sc, taking 6 + and 6 x;
- selection of the two edge candidates, taking two or three comparisons;
- selection of the single candidate, taking a 2D cross product, 3 + and 2 x and a comparison;
- computation of the interpolation parameter, 2 +, 1 /;
- final 3D interpolation, 3 +, 6 x.

Will be hard to do shorter.

Answer (score 0):

See the paper

> [Fast, minimum storage ray-triangle intersection](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/10867651.1997.10487468),
>   by Tomas Möller and Ben Trombone,
>   in 
>   *Journal of Graphics Tools*, 2(1):21–28, 1997.

See also [this page](http://www.graphics.cornell.edu/pubs/1997/MT97.html).

The authors say:

> One advantage of this method is that the plane equation need not be computed on the fly nor be stored, which can amount to significant memory savings for triangle meshes. As we found our method to be comparable in speed to previous methods, we believe it is the fastest ray-triangle intersection routine for triangles that do not have precomputed plane equations.